# Call named routes in CakePHP as the same way in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp, routes, url-routing

How can I call a route (in the view) in CakePHP as the same way in Rails?

**Ruby on Rails**

routes.rb

```
map.my_route '/my-route', :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'index'
```

view

```
link_to 'My Route Name', my_route_path
```

**CakePHP**

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/my-route', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'index'));
```

view

```
$html->link('My Route Name', '/my-route');
```

I think the Rails way is better, because I can make changes in the "url" and I don't need changes the code of all views.

Answer (score 3):

Use the array version in the view. CakePHP does reverse routing to determine the string link to use, i.e. '/my-route', from the array of controller / action / params in the array.

```
$html->link('My Route Name', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Also check out this from [Mark Gandolfo](http://github.com/markgandolfo/cakephp_named_route)